# Php/Mysql : CAST/CASE if row + '_remove' exists then don't select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, casting, case

I want a include a very specific `CAST/CASE` in my query, but I'm not really sure how to do this. Here is my SQL LINE :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (

         type = 'aaa' OR
         type = 'bbb' OR
         type = 'ccc' OR
         type = 'ddd')

         AND (points NOT LIKE '-%')

         ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

What I'm trying to perfom is that :

```
if   : 'type'_remove EXISTS and 'type'->data == 'type'_remove->data
then : Don't select the 'type' row.
```

Example, and what I want the query to select or not :

```
id    type          data  points
----------------------------------
1     aaa            1      1     don't select : aaa_remove exists and data are the same
2     bbb            1      3     select       : bbb_remove exists BUT data aren't the same
3     ddd            1     -1     don't select : points IS LIKE '-%'
4     aaa_remove     1     -1
5     ddd            1     -3     don't select : points IS LIKE '-%'
6     bbb_remove     2     -1
7     ccc            1      1     select       : ccc_remove doesn't exists with the same data
```

Comment: If points is a numeric datatype, surely you simply check for `< 0`; if it isn't numeric, why isn't it?

Comment: Cool! Yeah points is a BIGINT(20) So yeah I'm going to do that :) Thinx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a field called `removed`, which would make the whole thing much easier/cleaner, but if you have your reasons, you could try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table` AS `outer`
WHERE
    `outer`.`type` IN('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd') AND
    `outer`.`points` >= 0 AND
    (
        SELECT `inner`.`id`
        FROM `table` AS `inner`
        WHERE
            `inner`.`type` = CONCAT(`outer`.`type`, '_remove')  AND
            `inner`.`data` = `outer`.`data`
        LIMIT 1
    ) IS NULL
ORDER BY `outer`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Also, if you're going to have the same basic setup for many types, you could just select `type NOT LIKE '%_remove'` instead of listing all the types you want.

Comment: Think you dude! I'm currently testing it